# How do I write into a focused input with a virtual keyboard?

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard

I completed a tutorial to create a virtual keyboard for a application that I would prefer did not use the chrome o/s keyboard. The tutorial was great and the jquery is much simpler than I expected. However, it simply writes into a text input using the id as a selector. I would like to have it type directly into a focused input. I have not been able to find a way to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Here is the script:

```
 $(function(){
var $write = $('#write'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false;

$('#keyboard li').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        character = $this.html();


    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
        $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
        $('.symbol span').toggle();

        shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
        capslock = false;
        return false;
    }

            if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
        $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
        capslock = true;
        return false;
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
        var html = $write.html();

        $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
        return false;
    }


    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";


    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();


    if (shift === true) {
        $('.symbol span').toggle();
        if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

        shift = false;
    }

    $write.html($write.html() + character);
});
});
```

I have a number of inputs that I would like a user to be able to edit using this keyboard, here is what the html markup for these looks like:

```
    <input id="productC"  maxlength="3" class="menu" value="$8">
    <input id="priceCA" maxlength="3" class="menu" value="$10">
    <input id="priceCB" maxlength="3" class="menu" value="$8">
    <input id="priceCC" maxlength="3" class="menu" value="$12">
```

As a note, I attempted to switch the $write variable to the menu class. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$write.html($write.html() + character);
```

With

```
$(':focus').html($(':focus').html() + character);
```

The `$(':focus')` jQuery selector will return the current focused element. You should also check if the focused element is an input.

Comment: This looks like it should work... However, once I start typing on the keyboard the focus on the initial input is lost and it does not work. I will try to figure it out and if I can, I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: I have tried a few things and the keyboard is still not working. It just seems like the :focus is lost once the keyboard button is clicked. I tried changed the inputs tags to text areas. I tried a combination of class and focus selectors in the jquery. I'm made the keyboard container a parent of the inputs.